# Can't get nginx to match part of the path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have nginx running as in a docker-compose setup and I want to achieve to following:

Every url that contains `/something/` is passed to application 1
Every url that contains `/something/alsothis/` is passed to application 2

My current config has:

```
location ~* ^/something/(?<path>.+) {
            proxy_pass http://app1/$path;
        }

location ~* ^/something/alsothis/(?<path>.+) {
            proxy_pass http://app2/$path;
        }
```

When I try `https://www.example.com/something/rest_of_path` it is working fine.

However when I try `https://www.example.com/something/alsothis/rest_of_path` I get an `Unkown` error in Postman (500 error is logged in nginx).

Also I double checked that app2 is working. When I change to the first location to app2, it also works fine.

Can't seem to figure out what is going wrong, all help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regular expression are evaluated in order until a match is found. So you need to reverse those two `location` statements, because the first one also matches any URI intended for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Richard was right, just had to change the order.